# Decrypt 01 09 00 12 12 09 24 10 knowing encryption was doing with c=character $c^5\pmod{29}$

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

So the solution said in order to find out the original character number($A=0, B=1, C=2$, etc). That you have to find $5x\equiv1\pmod{28}$ so $x\equiv17\pmod{29}$, because $\phi(29)=28$. So the solution becomes $d$=encrypted word then c=$d^{17}\pmod{29}$ How does getting the $\phi$ give the equation for decryption when $e=5$ and $p=29$ in the equation $c^5\pmod{29}$?

Comment: Though not an answer, the decoded sequence is [1, 4, 0, 12, 12, 4, 20, 15](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P8W2OllLy1TVyNIqWSEtv0ghWSEzT6EoMS89VcPIUrOWq6AoM69EIzolGkQla8YiFKkbGCoYWCoYGCgYGoEQkG1komBooK5XXJCTWaKhrqCuGav5/z8A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that $\phi(29)=28$, as $29$ is prime. The encryption exponent is $5$ and so the decryption exponent is its inverse modulo $28$, which indeed is $17$.

So the decryption function is $x \to x^{17} \pmod{29}$. The inverse of an exponential function is another exponential function, over such a finite ring. The inverse of $e$ modulo $\phi(n)$ is the required exponent $d$.

So $1,9,0,12,12,9,24,10$ decrypted becomes

$1,4,0,12,12,4,20,15$ which is "beammeup" so "beam me up" (with 29 characters a space would have been nice...)

Comment: "The inverse of e modulo ϕ(n) is the required exponent d." Why is this the case is my main question. Why the inverse of $emod\phi(n)$ rather than just $e(modn)$?

Comment: @user8714896 that’s the proven fact for any $n$. It’s due to Fermat’s little theorem in your case. Euler generalised it using his $\phi$ function.